# Codeigniter Insert Code not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello in my codeigniter project one textbox field values is not inserting into db. 
[image: Sale View]

How to pass value from view to controller and vice-versa?

View Code( Here we enter the Ex-showromm Price,suppose 1500)

when we hit Bill button The  value have to enter into db and and print it as a bill.

> $actual_price=0;
>               if(count($list_product) >0) {

```
         foreach($list_product as $key=>$item) {
                $total +=$item['salePrice'];

    ?>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;<?=$item['model']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$item['variant']?>
         <br />&nbsp;<?=$item['vin']?> &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;
          <?=$item['saleQty']?></td>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" name="price" id="price" size="13px"/></td>
         <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" name="actual_price" id="actual_price" size="13px"/></td>
        </tr>


     <?php }}?>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E0DFE3" class="cont">&nbsp;<input name="tot_price" type="hidden" id="tot_price" size="50" value="<?=$total?>" /></td>
        <td colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E0DFE3" class="cont">&nbsp;<input name="actual_price" type="hidden" id="actual_price" size="50" value="<?=$actual_price?>" /></td>
```

Bill View

The value from the database has been passed to a variable  in the report
[image: Report View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a value to the view, you add it to an array and pass it to the view like so:

```
$Data['Pies'] = array('Cherry', 'Key Lime');
$Data['Cakes'] = array('Funfetti');
$Data['Paperplates'] = true;
$this->load->view('picnic', $Data);
```

CodeIgniter automatically unpacks the data on the view side, so you access it like so:

```
The first pie is <?=$Pies[0] ?>
<?php if ($Paperplates) { ?> 
    Don't bring plates <?php
} else { ?> 
    Bring plates please 
<?php }
```

will print:

```
The first pie is Cherry
Don't bring plates
```

Regarding returning values to the controller: you don't, at least not the way you're thinking. In order to get variables back you'll need them to be sent from the browser using a `POST` or `GET` request.

I suggest you start off by reading the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html).

Comment: Okay I understood what you  are suggesting...But in my case the data $data['arrtoolsId']  = $arrtoolsId;
  $data['saleCustomer'] =$saleCustomer;
  $data['saleCode'] =$saleCode;
  $data['saleId'] =$saleId;
  $data['saleDate'] =$date;
  $data['userinfo'] =$arrUser;
  $data['bank']  = $bank;
  $data['scheme']  = $schemeName;
  $data['wcoNo']  =$wcoNo;
  $data['actual_price'] =$this->input->post('actual_price');
  $this->load->view('header_login');
  $this->load->view('catalog/bill',$data);

Comment: hello sudowned in my case $data['actual_price']=$this->input->post('actual_price');

Comment: Using the above eg,i have changed my code like this  $data['actual_price'] =$actual_price; and now when i run the code i am getting the error that "
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: actaul_price

Filename: catalog/bill.php

Line Number: 164"

Comment: I suspect that you aren't passing $data to the view.

Comment: Hello sudowned how to pass value from view (ie,textbox value) to controller....i have done like this.. <form class="cmxform" id="saleForm" action="<?=site_url()?>/catalog/bill" method="post">           <td colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E0DFE3" class="cont">&nbsp;<input name="exshowroom" type="text" id="exshowroom" size="50" value="<?=$exshowroom;?>" /></td>

Comment: In controller (catalog/Bill)    $actual_price=$this->input->post('exshowroom');               $data['actual_price'] =$actual_price;
  $this->load->view('header_login');
  $this->load->view('catalog/bill',$data);

Comment: Insert code is            "actual_price"  =>$actual_price

     );
   $saleId=0;
   
    if($this->product_model->insert_sale_entry($arrInsert)){
      $saleId = $this->db->insert_id() ;              Is this the correct way/logic?

Answer (score 0):

Problem have been solved.
My changes to code are as follows

Sales Page

```
 <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" name="exshowroom" id="exshowroom" size="13px"/></td>
        </tr>
```

Controller

```
function bill()
{
$actual_price=$this->input->post('exshowroom'); 

$data['list_product'][0]['actual_price']=$actual_price;
}

$arrInsert  =array (
"actual_price"  =>$actual_price
);
        $saleId=0;

            if($this->product_model->insert_sale_entry($arrInsert)){
                    $saleId = $this->db->insert_id() ;
                    $arrStatus  =array (
                            "productSaleStatus" =>1
                                );
```

Passing Input value to Next View page ie,Report

```
$data['exshowroom'] =$this->input->post('exshowroom');
    $this->load->view('header_login');
    $this->load->view('catalog/bill',$data);
```

Reprort View Page

```
<td height="33" align="center" valign="middle" class="cont"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>Total Ex-ShowRoom Price of the Vehicle: </strong></font>: <font size="2">&nbsp;</font>
       <td align="center"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <?=$exshowroom?></font> </td>
        </tr>
```

Now am happy:)
Thanks to all